# Python: Crypto package error: "No module called '_number_new'"

Tags: python, package, cryptography

I have a software which installs its own local Python 3.9. Included in its python39/lib/site-packages is Crypto package, which causes errors and seems old and incompatible with Python 3.9. It includes long integers, like 1L, which I fixed by removing the "L". But I'm still getting the error below, even though the file

```
...\python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py
```

exists. For now, I'm trying to fix such errors manually, to avoid dealing with other incompatibility issues that will show up, if I try to update the whole Crypto  package. The line in number.py:

```
# New functions
from _number_new import *
```

Error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\Soft\python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\number.py", line 62,
> in <module>
>     from _number_new import *   File "C:\Program Files\Soft\python39\lib\site-packages-forced\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py",
> line 142, in _import
>     return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_number_new'
```

...\python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util listing:

[image: lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util]

Comment: Not sure about this, but perhaps try `from Crypto.Util._number_new ...`

Comment: @Swifty Thanks, it worked. Fixing long integers in other files now.

Comment: You're welcome; I read about modules and packages not too long ago, so I had doubts; you can try this one: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#python-packages. Now that you've confirmed it works I'll turn it into an answer :)

Comment: It's a bad idea to do something like `from <module> import *`. Everything from the module will be entered into your namespace, including things you have no knowledge of and that can surprise you and lead to hard to figure out bugs. Import exactly what you need and nothing else. Personally I try to avoid use `from ...` at all and stick to `import ...` and qualified references to module names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules in [packages](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#python-packages) can be accessed using dot notation, so you just need to:

```
from Crypto.Util._number_new import *
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just found the "2to3" Python tool, which (possibly) will fix the syntax changes to make Crypto work with Python 3. If it doesn't work, I'll try to replace Crypto with something else.